# How can I see who has the most of a certain badge?

Tags: discussion, badges, data-explorer

On a site, I've gotten 4 of a certain gold badge now and that made me curious to see who has the most, or maybe a list of users ordered by the number of times they've earned that badge.

I'm not familiar with the data API for SE and was wondering if someone knew of a search function written for this already? It seems plausible that I wouldn't be the first person interested in this particular query.

Edit: I'm particularly interested in a per-site query, but network wide would also be really interesting.

Comment: Per site or network wide?

Comment: @rene sorry, Ill edit - per site. Network wide would also be interesting, but I was particularly interested in per site.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This [query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/740037?badgename=*) does what you want:

```sql
-- badgename:badgename or * for all badges

select name
     , concat(
        'site://'
       , 'users/'
       , userid
       , '|'
       , u.displayname)
       as [User]
     , count(*) as[# of badges] 
from badges b
inner join users u on u.id = b.userid
where (##badgename:string?*## = '*' or name = ##badgename:string?*##)
group by name, userid, u.displayname
order by count(*) desc
```

You can either enter a single `*` to get a list of all badgenames and who earned the most or enter a specific badgename (or tagname for that matter) to find the league for a specific badge.

When run on Stack Overflow today this is the result for all badges:

[image]

Keep in mind SEDE is only updated once a week, on Sunday. To learn how to make your own queries take a look at the awesome [tutorial](https://data.stackexchange.com/tutorial).

Comment: This looks really cool, BUT I get this error when I try to specify a specific badge at the query you linked: "The query processor ran out of internal resources and could not produce a query plan. This is a rare event and only expected for extremely complex queries or queries that reference a very large number of tables or partitions. Please simplify the query. If you believe you have received this message in error, contact Customer Support Services for more information."

Comment: @Andrew that is now fixed. If you use the `[User Link]` magic column the query that gets run can have so many id's in its where clause that the query engine gives up. I made a slight adaption that gives the same result without relying on a magic column.